# Get result from form website operation

Tags: c#, error-handling, selenium

I want to get a result from the website when I submit a form. There are several things that can go wrong.

In a simple scenario I want to return:

`true` - when form was submitted

`false` - when form wasn't submitted

`null` - when we don't know if form was submitted or not

I did that ugly `try`, because of `NullReferenceException` (if form is filled correctly, there would be no `summary` element, and if form is filled incorrectly, there would be no `popup` element).

How can I make this more elegant?

```
public bool? GetResult(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var deadline = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);

    do
    {
        // check if success
        try
        {
            var success = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("summary")), "Success!"));
            if (success) return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  }

        // check if not enough data
        try
        {
            var notEnoughData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup")), "Not enough data"));
            if (notEnoughData) return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        // check if too much data
        try
        {
            var tooMuchData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup")), "Too much data"));
            if (tooMuchData) return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        // check if empty data
        try
        {
            var tooMuchData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup")), "Empty data"));
            if (tooMuchData) return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }


    } while (DateTime.Now > deadline);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should at least include code for `WebDriverWait` (so we can review async operations on it) and `Driver` (so we can try to avoid null reference exceptions). And use `StopWatch` for verifying elapsed time.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be your working code.

Comment: @dfhwze `WebDriverWait` is part of Selenium api: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp.

Comment: @Heslacher it is.

Comment: Well now the question is closed. Let me place a reopen-vote and hopefully the question will be reopened.

Comment: @Heslacher I still think the OP should provide more information about the UI. We need to be able to review his exception handling as well.

Comment: @dfhwze I don't see why we need the UI context here.

Comment: @Heslacher I would think to verify how to prevent the NRE he talks about in the 'ugly try' paragraph.

Comment: @dfhwze chack my answer about the NRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did that ugly try, because of NullReferenceException (if form is filled correctly, there would be no summary element, and if form is filled incorrectly, there would be no popup element).

This problem can be easyly handled by a `null` check of the returned `WebElement` from the call to `Driver.FindElement()`.

A little bit more problematic is IMO the looping condition because the condition only could evaluate to `true` if the passed `TimeSpan` is negativ. If this is what you want you really should place a comment there. If you didn't mean to pass a negative timespan then you should reverse the looping condition to `DateTime.Now < deadline`.

Extracting the repeated call to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)` to a variable will make the code easier to read.

You know although copy & pasta will save time, you need to check if the pasted code is correct (empty data vs tooMuchData)

> ```
>     // check if empty data
>     try
>     {
>         var tooMuchData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
>     .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup")), "Empty data"));
>         if (tooMuchData) return false;
> ```

Implementing the mentioned points will look like so

```
public bool? GetResult(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var deadline = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
    var waitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    do
    {
        WebElement summaryWebElement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("summary"));
        if (summaryWebElement != null)
        {
            var success = new WebDriverWait(Driver, waitTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(summaryWebElement , "Success!"));
            if (success) return true;
        }

        WebElement popupWebElement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup"));
        if (popupWebelement != null)
        {
            var notEnoughData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, waitTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(popupWebElement, "Not enough data"));
            if (notEnoughData) return false;

            var tooMuchData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, waitTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(popupWebelement, "Too much data"));
            if (tooMuchData) return false;

            var emptyData = new WebDriverWait(Driver, waitTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(popupWebElement, "Empty data"));
            if (emptyData) return false;
        }

    } while (DateTime.Now > deadline);

    return null;
}
```

Because the checks for the popup text only differs from the expected text you could think about using a foreach loop over an array containing the expected strings.

Comment: the only thing I would change is to get rid of that DateTime for checking elapsed time.